# How to migrate an Oracle PL/SQL procedure to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to migrate an Oracle stored procedure (PL/SQL) to PostgreSQL (pl/pgsql). I can't figure out how to do it.

```
Procedure Check_File ( strLine in varchar2 , lngRecord in number ) is
  type tab_str is table of varchar2(500) index by binary_integer;
  tabline   tab_str;
  intp1     integer;
  intp2     integer;
  intsize   integer;
begin

  -- Split line into table
  intp1 := 1 ;
  intp2 := instr ( strline , ';' , intp1 ) ;
  intsize := 0;
  while intp2 != 0 loop
    intsize := intsize + 1 ;
    tabline(intsize) := trim(substr ( strLine , intp1 , intp2-intp1 ));
    intp1 := intp2 + 1 ;
    intp2 := instr ( strline , ';' , intp1 ) ;
  end loop;
  intsize := intsize + 1 ;
  tabline(intsize) := trim(substr ( strLine , intp1 ));

  if intsize <> 23 then
    utl_file.put_line ( olog , 'Block - Record ' || lngRecord || ' - Incorrect number of fields') ;
    raise oExcept;
  end if;
end;
```

this is what i did:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Check_File ( strLine in text , lngRecord in bigint ) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
DECLARE

  intp1     integer;
  intp2     integer;
  intsize   integer;


   -- CREATE TYPE tab_str AS (tab2 text[]);  
   tabline   tab_str;
BEGIN

    -- Split line into table
    intp1 := 1 ;
    intp2 := instr ( strline , ';' , intp1 ) ;
    intsize := 0;
    while intp2 != 0 loop
      intsize := intsize + 1 ;
      tabline(intsize) := trim(substring(strLine  from intp1  for intp2-intp1 ));
      intp1 := intp2 + 1 ;
      intp2 := instr ( strline , ';' , intp1 ) ;
    end loop;
    intsize := intsize + 1 ;
    tabline(intsize) := trim(substring(strLine  from intp1 ));

    if intsize <> 23 then
      utl_file.put_line ( olog , 'Block - Record ' || lngRecord || ' - Incorrect number of fields') ;
      raise oExcept;
    end if;

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: I think the splitting of the line can be done much easier in Postgres with a simple `tabline := string_to_array(strline, ';')`. If you are looking for an equivalent to `utl_file` you could use the extension orafce: https://github.com/orafce/orafce

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward.

- Define a function with `RETURNS void` if you don't need to return anything.
- Declate `tabline` as `text[]` (array of `text`). See the documentation [how to handle arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html).
- Use functions from the [`adminpack`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/adminpack.html) contrib module to write to a file on the database server.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) will help you solve the remianing questions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have done that but still have a problem with the tabline syntaxe "tabline(intsize)"..

Comment: You should `DECLARE tabline text[];`. I have expanded the answer a little. You'll have to change the code to PostgreSQL array syntax.

Comment: yes i've figure out what was the problem.. tabline has to be an array..
so i did this:

tabline [ intsize ] := trim(substring(strLine  from intp1  for intp2-intp1 ));

i don't have no syntax error anymore.

thank you